# Qt update() doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have a problem , that update() function in `QGraphicsItem` doesn't work. What I want to do is , when I move circle , other `QGraphicsItem`( in the mean time roundrect ) changes color.
This is a example, what I want to do:

circle.cpp:

```
void CircleItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    // RoundRect Object
    RectItem->SetBackGround();
    QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent( event );
}
```

RoundRect.cpp:

```
void RoundRectItem::SetBackGround()
{
    ChangeBackground = true;
    update();
}

void RoundRectItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QRectF rec = QRectF( QPoint( 0,0 ), boundingRect().size() / 2 );

    roundRect = QRectF(rec.adjusted(-rec.height() / 2, 0, rec.height()/2, 0));

    roundRect.moveTo( boundingRect().center().x() - roundRect.width() / 2,
                      boundingRect().center().y() - roundRect.height() / 2 );

    if( !ChangeBackground )
        painter->setBrush( backBrush );
    else
        painter->setBrush( QBrush( Qt::blue ) );

    painter->setPen( QColor( 255,255,255 ) );

    painter->drawRoundedRect(roundRect, roundRect.height() / 2, roundRect.height() / 2 );
}
```

So the question is, how can I make this `update()` work right.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: From my code, you can see, that I'm setting bool varible "Change Background", when the circle is moving, and then I must repaint the roundrect, that's why I call update() to change the background color of the roundrect , while the circle is moving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking the update() method of QGraphicsItem. You should call the update() of the QGraphicsView you are working with. For example you can keep your QGraphicsView as a member class of your item like:

```
QGraphicsView * parent;
```

And call it's update method when you want the changes take place like:

```
void RoundRectItem::SetBackGround()
{
    ChangeBackground = true;
    parent->update();
}
```

Comment: Why can't I just call the update() method from QGraphicsItem class? And create a view and by view update parents? Why? Why invoking graphicsitem updates won't work and graphicsview will? And btw QGraphicsView , doesn't have a update() method, just looked in the docs.

Comment: Though it has a function ViewportUpdateMode, mb overloading this function rly can help.

Comment: The update() method is derived from QWidget. You should force update by updating the whole view or scene. The update() method of QGraphicsItem just schedules a repaint. The paint() function is called by QGraphicsView to paint the item's contents.

Comment: Ok, now I faced a problem, my class is inherited from QGraphicsItem and this update requires QWidget, let us think on that one.

Comment: You need a QGraphicsScene and a QGraphicsView object to display your items.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that, the question is that all my objects that I'm drawing are QGraphicsItem, then I put them in QGraphicsScene and draw them in QMainWindow. I need to force one of the objects to redraw itself.If I use QWidget::update(), then it means, that I redraw the hole scene, but I need to redraw only 1 item. And from that point( in QMainWindow ) I think I can't handle the movement of an item( but I'm not sure ).

Comment: So the main question now is how to call repaint from QGraphicsItem?

Comment: updating view does not necessarily redraw the hole scene. You can set QGraphicsView::ViewportUpdateMode to redarw full or parts of the view.

Comment: Ok , but how to call that thing from item classes , cause they don't know about scene or view, that's the main thing I'd like to know.And btw that thx for answering my stupid questions.

Comment: As i said in the answer you can keep the view as a member of your class RoundRectItem. You can pass your view to the item as a constructor argument.